# Cucumber plugin installation issue in eclipse IDE

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have some concern over installation of cucumber plugin in eclipse IDE.
I tried in every possible way but there is some installation issue.
You quick help will be greatly appreciated.

Eclipse Version: Luna Service Release 2 (4.4.2) (Java)

Cucumber plugin link: http://cucumber.github.com/cucumber-eclipse/update-site

I am using above link (Eclipse -> Help -> Install New Software) along with other links too but unable to complete the installation.

Error: 
An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=epp.package.java, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.aspectj.runtime.source,1.7.3.20130613144500-a
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.contribution.weaving.jdt.source,2.2.3.e42x-RELEASE-20130625-1400
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.contribution.weaving.source,2.2.3.e42x-RELEASE-20130625-1400
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.contribution.xref.core.source,2.2.3.e42x-RELEASE-20130625-1400
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.contribution.xref.source,2.2.3.e42x-RELEASE-20130625-1400
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.contribution.xref.ui.source,2.2.3.e42x-RELEASE-20130625-1400

Thanks in advance.

Santosh

Comment: do you have the same problem with update site https://cucumber.io/cucumber-eclipse/update-site

Comment: Thanks MrSimpleMind. I tried but same issue as above with this link too.

Comment: Thank you all. I got a workaround and got the plugin from below source. https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/cucumber-jvm-eclipse-plugin